# What exactly does the existence of $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\log{a_n}$ imply about $a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have seen $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\log{a_n}=C$ being analyzed often and it is sort of saying that for large $n,$ $a_n \approx e^{nC} $. But I feel like this is not rigorous enough. What exactly does this limit say about our sequence $a_n$?

Any input would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So put the limit in $N$-$\epsilon$ form.

Comment: Whenever $u<e^C<v$, we have $u^n<a_n<v^n$ for almost all $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $a_n$ and $C$ are the same up to leading exponential order. Namely, $$\frac{1}{n} \log \frac{a_n}{C} = 0$$
Consider, for example, $a_n = e^{nC}$ and $b_n = ne^{nC}$. Then $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the same up to leading exponential order in the sense $$\frac{1}{n}\log \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$$ On the other hand, saying $a_n\approx b_n$ is misleading, in a certain sense.

This idea can be seen, for example, in large deviations. Let $Z,Z_1,\dots$ be i.i.d $\mathcal N(0,1)$ variates. Then for $x\geq 0$, $$P(\bar Z_n \geq x) \underset{n\to\infty}{\sim}\frac{1}{\sqrt n x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-nx^2/2}$$ (We use the notation $a_n\sim b_n$ iff $\lim a_n/b_n = 1$). On the other hand,
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log P(\bar Z_n \geq x) = -x^2/2$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a_n>0$ for all $n$ we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \log\sqrt[n]{a_n}=C$$
so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt [n]{a_n}$ does exist (namely, it would be $e^C$).

A sufficient condition for this is that the series of functions $\sum_{n\to\infty} a_nx^n$ converges at some interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: The convergence of the series does not imply the existence of the limit $\sqrt[n]{a_n}.$